# php java mysql Audio: Audio file on loop not playing

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have designed Sindhi (Indus) Alphabet voice on click, fetching filename and path from database table, here image is showing correctly with loop but audio is not playing and repeats first file sound on each button

```
    $pth1="voice/alifbepati/";
    $pth="images/ipapati/";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT ltrId, letter from letters order by ltrId";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

if (isset($row['ltrId'])) {$ltrId=$row['ltrId']; echo $ltrId;}
echo $pth1.$ltrId.".mp3";
global $filenm;
$filenm= $pth1.$ltrId.".mp3";
if (isset($ltrId)) {echo "<img src=\"$pth".$ltrId.".jpg\" width=75 height=75><BR>
<audio id=\"player\" src='$filenm'></audio>
<div>
    <button onclick=\"document.getElementById('player').play()\" title='$filenm'>Play</button>

</div>

";

}
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

Comment: Nothing to do with `java`

Comment: @ScaryWombat I think this was mistagged Java instead of JavaScript.

Comment: This is some extremely unruly code. Can you try and format this better so we can follow what you're trying to do?

Comment: on loop the image file name is changing but audio file name is not changing so each time button play same audio while image is diffrent

Answer (score 0):

on loop the image file name is changing but audio file name is not changing so each time button play same audio while image is diffrent

```
<?php
$pth1="voice/alifbepati/";
    $pth="images/ipapati/";
for ($x = 1; $x <= 52; $x++) {

echo $pth1.$x.".mp3";
global $filenm;
$filenm= $pth1.$x.".mp3";
echo "<img src=\"$pth".$x.".jpg\" width=75 height=75><BR>
<audio id=\"player\" src='$filenm'></audio>
<div>
    <button onclick=\"document.getElementById('player').play()\" title='$filenm'>Play</button>

</div>
   The number is: $x <br>";
} 
?>
```

Comment: please help why audio file name is not changing in action while image file name is changing and displaying